# can't enable row level security using sqlalchemy engine

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, supabase, row-level-security

I have my sqlalchemy engine setup as such:

```
DATABASE_URL = (
    f"postgresql://postgres:{PG_PASS}@db.blabla.supabase.co:5432/postgres"
)
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
```

And I use the following to try and create a table in supabase

```
def create_table(table_name):
    table_name = table_name.lower()
    # Create new table
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        # Create table
        query = text(
            f"""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} (
                id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
                user_id UUID references auth.users (id) NOT NULL
            );
            """
        )
        conn.execute(query)
        st.write(f'Table "{table_name}" created in database')

        # Enable RLS
        query = text(
            f"""
            ALTER TABLE {table_name} ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
            """
        )
        conn.execute(query)
        st.write(f'RLS for table "{table_name}" created in database')

        # Create Policy
        query = text(
            f"""
            CREATE POLICY "User can CRUD their own tables only"
            ON public.{table_name}
            FOR ALL
            TO authenticated
            USING (
                auth.uid() = user_id
            )
            WITH CHECK (
                auth.uid() = user_id
            );
            """
        )
        conn.execute(query)
        st.write(f'Policy for table "{table_name}" created in database')
```

This created the table, but neither enabled RLS nor created the policy.

In supabase, running this in the sql editor works:
`ALTER TABLE my_table ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;`

I am not sure how to troubleshoot

Comment: Do you ever commit the changes?

Comment: yes, the app is automatically saved and updated with streamlit. But I've also added restarted the app every time

Comment: or clarity: do you call `conn.commit()` in the code?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I don't. just the `conn.execute()`

Comment: Then try calling `conn.comit()` after executing. IIRC, Postgres has transactional DDL.

Comment: @snakecharmerb you either set auto-commit on the engine level or it won't commit without an explicit call. It doesn't matter which RDBMS you're using

Comment: Enable the echo option when creating your `engine = sa.create_engine(db_uri, echo=True)` and check if this is logged when you run your program `INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
Policy for table "users" created in database`. I was unable to reproduce your issue btw.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments from @snakecharmerb and @Oluwafemi Sule I got this to work. Running `create_engine(..., echo=True`) allows me to see logs of what's being executed.

And separating the functions ending with `commit` and `close`:

```
def create_table(table_name):
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        # Create table
        query = text(
            f"""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} (
                id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
                user_id UUID references auth.users (id) NOT NULL
            );
            """
        )
        conn.execute(query)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```